# Postfix SMTP on Remote Server Responds 554 Relay Access Denied for rcpt (recipient). Works okay on 'localhost' smtp server

Tags: smtp, postfix-mta

I'm trying to send e-mail through  a remote vm running `postfix` as an smtp server.

However, I'm receiving a `554 - Relay access denied` error when sending the `rcpt` cmd.

```
(554, b'5.7.1 <xxxxx@xyz.org>: Relay access denied')
```

I understand that it is denying the e-mail address I'm attempting to set as a recipient, but I don't understand why.

The socket connection itself establishes fine, and I'm able to send a `mail` cmd prior to attempting `rcpt`.

Environment Details:

Host Machine:

> Windows 7 machine / Language: Python 3.

Guest VM:

> Docker container (Ubuntu) VM running `postfix`, `ssh` -- with dhcp-assigned ip address `10.35.50.166`.

This is the `python` code running:

(on host machine):

```
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP(host='10.35.50.166', port=8025)

server.mail('xxxxx@xyz.org')
(250, b'2.1.0 Ok')

server.rcpt('xxxxx@xyz.org')
(554, b'5.7.1 <xxxxx@xyz.org>: Relay access denied')
```

Running from the guest machine, the *error does not occur*:

```
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP(host='localhost', port=8025)

server.mail('xxxxx@xyz.org')
(250, b'2.1.0 Ok')

server.rcpt('xxxxx@xyz.org')
(250, b'2.1.5 Ok')
```

Comment: Mar 24 22:57:38 04305ce1d661 postfix/smtpd[25121]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[172.17.42.1]: 554 5.7.1 <xxxxx@xyz.org>: Relay access denied; from=<xxxxx@xyz.org> to=<xxxxx@xyz.org> proto=SMTP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postfix' default configuration on Ubuntu allows relay access only on the local interface (i.e. localhost). When connecting on other interfaces (VM network), it requires SMTP authentication.

So you could either add authentication to your SMTP call or add your host ip to the allowed relay networks.

To achive the later, find the line in your `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file that reads

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
```

and change it to

```
127.0.0.0/8,10.0.0.0/8
```

Then reload postfix with

```
sudo postfix reload
```

Edit:
Alternatively, you could set the `mynetworks_style` setting to

```
mynetworks_style = subnet
```

See [BASIC CONFIGURATION README](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html#relay_from)

Comment: Spent 3 hrs digging into the problem which was exactly the same as that one. Thanks for helping!

Comment: You are my hero <3

Answer (score 0):

There will be a config error in main.cf on the postfix server which hasn't set your local network to allow to relay.

Your need something like

Localnetworks=0.0.0.0/24 (your network or ip is guest machine)

Answer (score 0):

Issue is fixed. This is configuration I'm using now. Issue was with the `mynetworks` directive thanks to `itchee`.

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = localhost
#myorigin = $mydomain
#relayhost = $mydomain


alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = localdomain, localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost

relayhost =

#mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::]/128 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128

mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 10.0.0.0/8 172.0.0.0/8 [::]/128 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128


mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +


#inet_interfaces = localhost
```

Comment: Hi eclewlow, Welcome to the Stack Exchange network!
Since it was itchee's answer that helped you solve your problem, you should accept their answer to give them the credit and to inform others that your issue is resolved. For more info, see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  Also: this is more of a system administration than a programming-related question so it’s off-topic for StackOverflow. Server Fault has over [3,000 Postfix questions tag](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/postfix?sort=newest).